# OO design - injecting factories deep into hierarchical class structure

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a hierarchical class structure. Let's say I am modelling students in a city:

```
class District {
    private Map<String, School> schools;

    public School getSchool(String name) {
        School school = schools.get(name);
        if (school == null) {
            school = new School();
            schools.put(name, school);
        return school;
    }
}
```

and

```
class School {
    private Map<String, Classroom> classrooms;

    public Classroom getClassroom(String name) {
        // similar lazy init code
    }
}
```

and

```
class Classroom {
    private Map<String, Pupil> pupils;

    public Pupil getPupil(String name) {
        // similar lazy init code
    }
}
```

and finally

```
class Pupil {
    private PupilProfile profile = new DefaultPupilProfile();
}
```

Each object is dynamically and lazily created as it is required.

Now lets say I want to use different implementations of PupilProfile depending on (for sake of argument) the pupil's age. However, I don't want to put the logic of which PupilProfile implementation is used in Pupil - I want to separate it out. I may want to change it in future.

I write a factory interface:

```
interface PupilProfileFactory {

    PupilProfile newPupilProfile(Pupil pupil);

}
```

and my initial implementation:

```
class AgeDependentPupilProfileFactory implements PupilProfileFactory {
    @Override
    public PupilProfile newPupilProfile(Pupil pupil) {
        switch (pupil.getAge()) {
            // Case statements returning different implementations
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation exists as a singleton in my application (eg in the Spring app context).

My problem is that I now have to get this factory into the Pupil:

```
class Pupil {
    private PupilProfile profile = new DefaultPupilProfile();

    public Pupil(PupilProfileFactory factory) {
        this.profile = factory.newPupilProfile(this);
    }
}
```

In practise this means passing the PupilProfileFactory down every layer of the object graph, from top (District) to bottom (Pupil) via constructors or setters. Each intermediate layer needs to have a field for this factory, even though they only use it to pass it down to the level below when they lazily create one.

This strikes me as ugly (and a pain to refactor) and I'm sure there must be a better way - is there?

Comment: Any reason you can't use Spring to inject the appropriate implementation into the constructor of the Pupil class?

Comment: Because they aren't Spring bean, they're POJOs. I could make them Spring prototypes, to take care of the autowiring for me, but that would mean 1) heavily depending on Spring and 2) injecting the ApplicationContext into every level of the hierarchy, so not really any better